# How the super and this keywords work in a subclass method

Tags: java

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";

    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}

public class Cougar extends Feline {

    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar ");
    }
    void go() {
        type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }
}
```

In this code output is coming as `feline cougar c c` and when I am changing subclass variable as `String Type = "c"` means assigning new String type then answer is coming as `feline cougar f f` please let me know how this and super keyword is working in this subclass method?

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. Please read [mcve] and beyond that do some research/study to at least be able to express your problem in a way we could help with.

Comment: Your variable type isn't declared - the insufficient code in your question would not even compile...

Comment: If you declare a `type` variable in `Cougar` it shadows the one in `Feline`, so `this.type` and `super.type` refer to different variables. If you don't, they refer to the same variable.

Comment: which variable are you talking about? type variable is already publically defined and in the subclass, we are just changing the value of the same variable

Comment: @Sanat There is no `type` variable in the subclass in the code you posted. Please read what I wrote again. When you *added* `String type = "c"` into the subclass you introduced the shadowing I spoke of.

Comment: that's absolutely fine "type" given in the subclass is shadowing the actual value and this is the actual question which is being asked in OCPJP java. and the output of this code is coming as "feline cougar c c"

Comment: That's what I said. Your point?

Comment: I think my point is already cleared by "Sweeper".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is an unqualified name, and refers to a *local variable*, *parameter*, or *field*.
`this.type` refers to a *field* accessible to the *current* class.
`super.type` refers to a *field* accessible to the *base* class.

Since the subclass `Cougar` does not have a *field* named `type`, both `this.type` and `super.type` refers to the `type` field declared in base class `Feline`. In your example, there is no difference between `this` and `super`.

The statement `type = "c ";` in method `go()` is unqualified, and since there is no local variable or parameter by that name, it also refers to field `type` of base class `Feline`. As such, `type`, `this.type`, and `super.type` all refer to the one and only field named `type`.

If the statement in method `go()` is changed to `String Type = "c";`, then it defines a differently named local variable. Remember, Java names are case-sensitive, so `Type` and `type` are not the same name. So, field `type` retains the initialized value of `"f "`.

If you intended to change the statement in method `go()` to `String type = "c";`, then it defines and initialize a *local variable* named `type`. By nature, it cannot update *field* `type`, since the initializer applies to the newly declared *local variable*. So, field `type` retains the initialized value of `"f "`.

If you first declare the local variable in method `go()` using `String type;`, then assign it like you original code does using `type = "c";`, then the unqualified name refers to the *local variable*, not the *field*, by that name. The local variable is [*hiding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) the field of the same name. So, once again, field `type` retains the initialized value of `"f "`.

Comment: why I am able to shadowing the type variable at method level and not at subclass level. ?

Comment: @Sanat I don't understand your comment. You can hide base class field using a subclass field *and* using a local variable, both at the same time, if you want. If you do both, then subclass field hides super class field, and local variable hides both fields, in which case `type`, `this.type` and `super.type` would refer to 3 different variables.

Comment: Agree.. but When I am writing type = "c" at subclass level (not in method), it is giving me compile time error as "Syntax error on token "type", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" means I have to assign String type, but at method level I was just changing the variable value which was declared in parent class

Comment: @Sanat `type = "c"` is an assignment statement. Statements must be in a method, constructor, or initializer block. That's why it cannot be outside a method. You can put it in an initializer block, which is basically the same as putting it inside the constructor, if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, man ! you cleared my doubt, I understood now.

Answer (score 1):

Now I see that . **Your Cougar class is missing "type" variable**. I have checked in my code and this.type and super.type are the same variable. Setting type = "c" is equal to this.type = "c" and super.type="c" because they point same field.

Edited:  Write something like this

```
class Cougar extends Feline {
    public String type = "c ";
    ....
}
```

Comment: that's fine, you have created a new variable at subclass level and it is working as expected, but my question was to understand the behavior of the code posted by me and why I am able to shadowing the type variable at method level and not at subclass level. ?

Comment: In your case you have "only one field". Then why  are you thinking that this.type and super.type should give you different field, when you have only "ONE". As I say in answer super.type and this.type point same field. This is default behavior, if you have "ONE" field .  You did'n shadow variable you just set new value to only field you have. I hope that helps.